# Bound on correlation derived from geometric interpretation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

[Since correlations are cosines](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/17/covariance-and-law-of-cosines/), for three random variables such that $\operatorname{corr}(A, B)=b$, $\operatorname{corr}(A, C)=c$ and $\operatorname{corr}(B, C)=a$, one must have
$$
a \geqslant b c-\sqrt{1-b^{2}} \sqrt{1-c^{2}}
$$
How can I prove the above?

I am fine up to $1-a^2+b(b-ca)-c(ba-c) \ge 0$ using Sylvestor's criterion.